# What is the best way to collect exception in non-blocking for-loop iteration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller method that invoke other method `TryDoSomethingAsync()`

```
public Task<ActionResult> ControllerMethod() {
    await TryDoSomethingAsync();
    return Ok();
}


public async Task TryDoSomethingAsync() {
    for(... in ...) {
        try {
                ...
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
                swallow the exception here
        }
    }
 }
```

The method contains try-catch inside the for-loop so that any failure won't block the others. However, this make the method unable to reflect the detail of each exception and then nobody knows what happen internally if an exception caught.

Is there a better approach to track the detail of the exception while it doesn't block the entire iteration? Currently I got 2 options so far:

1. Specifying an `out` argument to store the error messages. This is the most effective way but the only concern is messing up with the argument would make the signature more confusing as most of the `out` argument intends to be the result of the method.
2. Using a singleton instance that keep track of the exceptions. This is the last thing I would do as there is concurrency issue and it just makes the entire approach more complex and hard to maintain.

Comment: how about logging?

Comment: Add a `List<Exception>` as a variable outside the loop and populate it inside the loop? That seems like the most obvious and straightforward way of solving this.

Comment: Throw an [`AggregateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-5.0) after the loop ends...

Comment: @HereticMonkey hmm, this sounds promising, but wouldn't it throw exception anyway even if there is no exception thrown inside the loop?

Comment: I suggest reading [.NET Matters - Aggregating Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/brownfield/aggregating-exceptions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to return many exceptions is to create a `List<Exception>` variable and add all the exceptions to it in a `catch` block. Then, after your main iteration is done, if the `exceptions` list contains any items, you can throw all of them in an `AggregateException` object:

```
public async Task TryDoSomethingAsync() 
{
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    foreach(thing in things)
    {
        try 
        {
            // Do something
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            // Add the exception to our list
            exceptions.Add(ex);
        }
    }

    if (exceptions.Any())
    {
        throw new AggregateException("There were exceptions", exceptions);
    }
 }
```

Then when you want to examine and handle the exceptions, you can use the `InnerExceptions` property of the `AggreageException` to get each exception:

```
public Task<ActionResult> ControllerMethod() 
{
    try
    {
        await TryDoSomethingAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae) 
    {
        // Do something with the exceptions if needed
        foreach (var ex in ae.InnerExceptions)
        {
            LogException($"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Alterantively, you could use the [`Handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.handle?view=net-5.0) method of the `AggregateException` if you want to handle specific exceptions.

See the `AggregateException` class [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-5.0) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AggregateException` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-5.0)) and then `handle` each one of them or specific kind of exception:

```
try
{
    foreach (var c in results)
    {
    }
}
catch (OperationCanceledException e)
{
    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        Console.WriteLine($"Canceled");
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    ae.Handle(e =>
    {
        if (x is UnauthorizedAccessException) // If you don't want to handle.
        {                  
            return false;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.GetType().Name}: {e.Message}");
        return true;
    });
}
```